# Format a pandas object column

Tags: pandas, jupyter, pydub

I have a pandas DataFrame where one of the columns is filled with [Pydub](http://pydub.com/) `AudioSegment` objects.

I can display a single `AudioSegment` as an HTML audio player by just doing this in a cell:

```py
from pydub import AudioSegment
AudioSegment.from_wav("never_gonna_give_you_up.wav")
```

However, when I display the pandas DataFrame, I just get a column filled with object references: `(((<pydub.audio_segment.AudioSegment object at...`

What I would like is for the column to fill with HTML audio players so I can view the metadata and listen to the clips.

Comment: how are you displaying the dataframe?  `df.head()`?

Comment: I use `df[df.column>threshold]` to look at slices of the dataset.

Comment: I think you would need to put this into html, several methods [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html) might help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, Here is how I managed to display audio files in dataframe in Jupyter

```
import IPython.display as ipd

df['wav_pydub'] = df['wav_pydub'].apply(lambda x:x._repr_html_().replace('\n', '').strip(), axis=1)
df_html = df.to_html(escape=False, index=False)

ipd.display(ipd.HTML(table_html))
```